# Impossible to insert a string in a cell from the Dialog Box in Desktop Excel 365 (Windows)

Tags: office365, ms-office, office-js, excel-addins

*Precondition:*

- Platform: PC desktop.
- Host: Excel
- Excel version: Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.13127.20402) 64-bit
- Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 1909

After opening the dialog box from the Ribbon and clicking the "Insert from dialog" button, the string is not inserted into a cell (it may be inserted once with a delay, but it stops working after it). The same script is working if we run it from the Task pane. For details,  please, see a video attached below.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WySvyPNqxFYrjg-Ewv_DtwcAKc0zFJv8/view?usp=sharing

We've added code to the excel-shared-runtime-scenario example. Please take a look
https://github.com/TheSorbex/PnP-OfficeAddins/commit/9f2300c8f3da2cc37068cc74aacb7df32dfe7320

How could we handle it?

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't work at all actually.

See the "Important" note in this section [Send information from the dialog to the host page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#send-information-from-the-dialog-box-to-the-host-page). Only 2 Office JavaScript APIs work in the dialog.

The workaround is to use `messageParent` to send the data to the host page. A handler on the host page for the Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived event then interacts with the workbook. See that same section I linked to for details.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
We simplified the code and checked all steps according to the official documentation. Please take a look at the code
https://github.com/TheSorbex/PnP-OfficeAddins/commit/4f7b26ceb965fdc4b826b4c9e3a68d917d75cbb6
and video
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WySvyPNqxFYrjg-Ewv_DtwcAKc0zFJv8/view?usp=sharing
1. In commands.ts we have added the openDialogueModal function, which opens a page in a dialog-box using displayDialogAsync.
2. When a user clicks on the button in the dialog box, we pass the data using messageParent
Please see the continuation below

Comment: 3. We receive data in commands.ts using dialog.addEventHandler (Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage).
Inside the processMessage function we process data and insert a string into the cell.

As a result, a string is not inserted into the cell with an open dalog-box.
In the first message, it was shown that we can insert a string into a cell when clicking on a button on the task pane. But we cannot insert a string when clicking on a button from a dialog box.

Comment: It looks like a bug. This problem is reproducible on Excel for Windows. Could you test the ability to insert a string into a cell from the dialog-box and give us some advice?

Note:
1. We took the excel-shared-runtime-scenario from the github as a base.

2. In our task, when the dialog-box is open, we need to insert a string into the cell and move to the adjacent cell below without closing the dialog-box.

Comment: If the host page closes the dialog before it tries to insert the string, does the string get inserted? Also, as an experiment, try making a taskpane the host page for the dialog instead of a function file opened from a button. See if that works.

Comment: If the host page closes the dialog before string insertion, it is not inserted. Also, if the taskpane is the host page for the dialog, the string does not get inserted as well.
For details see a video below https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ExTbsuK_K1c64zFi9jzFXYmF5Wmznlgm/view?usp=sharing
This problem is reproducible on Excel for Windows.

Could you try to reproduce this scenario and let us know the results, please?
Maybe, this is a bug, and you could fix it in the nearest future? Or, may we miss something when working with dialog boxes, and that's why the issue raised?

Comment: Try raising this as a probable bug on the office-js repo: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose

Comment: Hi Rick!
Could you, please, help us one more time? We asked this question on GitHub, but we received no answer. Maybe, you have an idea how could we force it?

Comment: I've asked internally for someone to give you an update in the GitHub issue.